# Text content did not match error when hot reloading lazy loaded chunks. Webpack 4, React-Router 4, loadable-components 1.2

Tags: webpack, universal, chunks, react-hot-loader, webpack-4

I have an universal boilerplate that works 99%.
The problem is when I hot reload after code change the page shows the correct output, but If I do an refresh of the page I get an error like this.

```
Warning: Text content did not match. Server: "HOME" Client: "HOM E"
```

The server does not update, but the client does, even on refresh.

I don't know whats wrong and I have googled it a lot :)

this is the code for creating chunks.

```
import { hot } from 'react-hot-loader';
import loadable from 'loadable-components';
const HomeBundle = loadable(() => import('./Home'), {
  modules: ['./Home']
})
export const Home = hot(module)(HomeBundle);
const AboutBundle  = loadable(() => import('./About'), {
  modules: ['./About'],

})
export const Home = hot(module)(AboutBundle);
```

this the server implementation

```
const initialState = store.getState();

const Code = <Provider store={store}>
    <Router context={{}} location={req.url}>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </Provider>

  getLoadableState(Code).then(loadableState => {
    const html = renderToString(Code)

    const fullPage = renderFullPage(html, initialState, loadableState, headAssets, isDeveloping);
    res.status(200).send(fullPage);
  });
```

and this is the client entry point.

```
import React from 'react';
import { hydrate } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from '../shared/App';
import configureStore from './../shared/redux/store';
import { loadComponents } from 'loadable-components'

import('whatwg-fetch');
import("./styles/root.scss");

// Create Redux store with initial state
const preloadedState = window.__PRELOADED_STATE__
delete window.__PRELOADED_STATE__;
const store = configureStore(preloadedState);

loadComponents().then(() => {
  hydrate((
    <Provider store={store}>
      <Router>
        <App />
      </Router>
    </Provider>
 ), document.getElementById('root'));
})
```

If someone knows how to solve this, or have any ideas I would be really grateful :)